# How to monitor a Windows Service on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-oms

I have a windows service running on a Azure VM availability set.

What is the best way to instrument monitoring for this service utilizing any of the Azure monitoring solutions?

Comment: It depends, what is it you want to monitor? The utilization of the VM (SS), the behavior of your service (and if so, what exactly) or...?

Comment: At the fundamental level the health of the service - whether it is up and running or not.

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? If you have more question, please let me know. If it works for you, could you please mark it as answer? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to monitor if it's running or not, you can use Log Analytics. More details please refer to this [article](https://cloudadministrator.net/2018/01/24/monitoring-windows-services-sates-with-log-analytics/).

I have tested it at my side, it works well.

1.Create a workspace and Enable the Log Analytics VM Extension as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm#create-a-workspace).

2.Once step 1 is completed, nav to your workspace -> in the left panel, select Advanced settings -> Data -> Windows Event Logs, then in the textbox, type "system", then select system in the dropdown -> click the add button.

[image]

3.click Save button.

[image]

4.In the left panel, click Logs. Then in the query editor, type the following command(please note that the == is case sensitive):

```
Event
| where TimeGenerated >ago(1d)
| where EventLog  == "System" and EventID ==7036 and Source == "Service Control Manager" 
| parse kind=relaxed EventData with * '<Data Name="param1">' Windows_Service_Name '</Data><Data Name="param2">' Windows_Service_State '</Data>'*
//you can add a filter by service name here like    | where Windows_Service_Name =="Windows Update"
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| project Computer, Windows_Service_Name, Windows_Service_State, TimeGenerated
```

5.The test result:

[image]

Comment: Does this capture whether a windows Service silently dies reporting no errors ?